# Let the user choose what type of document to open

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, usability, nsdocument

I'm creating an NSDocument application, with two document types: Website and Web Service. This is in my Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>Website</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
   <array>
    <string>website</string>
   </array>
   <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
   <true/>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Editor</string>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Default</string>
   <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
   <string>AWWebSite</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>Web Service</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
   <array>
    <string>webservice</string>
   </array>
   <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
   <true/>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Editor</string>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Default</string>
   <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
   <string>AWWebService</string>
  </dict>
 </array>
```

Now, whenever the user opens the application, selects the 'New' item from the menubar, or clicks the Dock icon while there are no open windows, I want to show a window with two options, each for one of the document types. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: I guess you may need to subclass NSDocumentController and override the newDocument: method in order to present your window with these options. You may take a look at Apple's document about the document-based applications. http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Tasks/SubclassController.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is override `- [NSDocumentController newDocument:]`. `NSDocumentController` is part of the responder chain and is the object that eventually handles the `newDocument:` message it sends.

From there, you can show whatever dialog you like and then call `makeUntitledDocumentOfType:error:`, `addDocument:`, `makeWindowControllers` and `showWindows`. This is what [`openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocumentController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000030-CJBCHIAE) does.

But the catch is that `NSDocumentController` is a singleton, so you need to make sure it's your subclass that gets instantiated, not Apple's. Typically, you do this by adding an object of your subclass to MainMenu.xib or whatever NIB gets loaded first. That's usually good enough to make sure that your subclass gets created first and becomes the singleton.

Comment: Thanks alot! I get this working for the menu item but not the Dock icon and the Application startup =[

Comment: You could override `openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:` instead; I believe this is what is called when you click the dock icon and when the app starts.